# Airflow: How to push xcom value from BigQueryOperator?

Tags: airflow

This is my operator:

```
bigquery_check_op = BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='bigquery_check',
    bql=SQL_QUERY,
    use_legacy_sql = False,
    bigquery_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
    trigger_rule='all_success',
    xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

When I check the Render page in the UI. Nothing appears there.
When I run the SQL in the console it return value `1400` which is correct.
Why the operator doesn't push the XCOM?

I can't use `BigQueryValueCheckOperator`. This operator is designed to FAIL against a check of value. I don't want nothing to fail. I simply want to branch the code based on the return value from the query.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you might be able to accomplish this with the BigQueryHook and the BranchPythonOperator:

```
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.contrib.hooks import BigQueryHook

def big_query_check(**context):
    sql = context['templates_dict']['sql']
    bq = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id='default_gcp_connection_id',
                        use_legacy_sql=False)
    conn = bq.get_conn()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    results = cursor.execute(sql)

    # Do something with results, return task_id to branch to
    if results == 0:
        return "task_a"
    else:
        return "task_b"

  
sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sales"


branching = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='branching',
    python_callable=big_query_check,
    provide_context= True,
    templates_dict = {"sql": sql}
    dag=dag,
)
```

First we create a python callable that we can use to execute the query and select which task_id to branch too. Second, we create the BranchPythonOperator.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is because `xcom_push` is not one of the params in [`BigQueryOperator`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py#L32) nor [`BaseOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/models.html#BaseOperator) nor LoggingMixin.

The [`BigQueryGetDataOperator`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_get_data.py) does return (and thus push) some data but it works by table and column name. You could chain this behavior by making the query you run output to a uniquely named table (maybe use `{{ds_nodash}}` in the name), and then use the table as a source for this operator, and *then* you can branch with the [`BranchPythonOperator`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/operators/python_operator.py#L103).

You might instead try to use the `BigQueryHook`'s [`get_conn().cursor()`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py#L1316) to run the query and work with some data *inside* the `BranchPythonOperator`.

Elsewhere we chatted and came up with something along the lines of this for putting in the callable of a `BranchPythonOperator`:

```
cursor = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id='connection_name').get_conn().cursor()
# one of these two:
cursor.execute(SQL_QUERY)  # if non-legacy
cursor.job_id = cursor.run_query(bql=SQL_QUERY, use_legacy_sql=False)  # if legacy
result=cursor.fetchone()
return "task_one" if result[0] is 1400 else "task_two"  # depends on results format
```